# Disable certain checkboxes in checkboxlist

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox list which consists of 13 different values, and i am trying to use jquery to disable all of them when 9, 10, and 11 are selected.

So when 9 is checked, all are disabled except 10 and 11. When 10 is selected all is disabled except 9 and 11. when 11 is selected all is disabled except 9 and 10

```html
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkboxlist1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="example1">     example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example2">   example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example3"> example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example4">    example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example5">     example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example6">    example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example7">     example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example8">   example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example9"> example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example10">    example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example11">     example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example12">    example </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="example13">    example </asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
            debugger;
            if (($("input[type='checkbox']")[9]).checked) {
                $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[9]).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else {
                $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[9]).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer:

```
<script>

    var indices = [9, 10, 11];

    indices.forEach(function (i) {
        $(".parent input[type='checkbox']").eq(i - 1).addClass("magic");
    });
    $(".parent input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("magic")) {
            if (this.checked)
                $(".parent input[type='checkbox']:not(.magic)").prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
            else {
                if ($(".parent input.magic[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 0)
                    $(".parent input[type='checkbox']:not(.magic)").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
     label {display: block;}
.magic + span {font-weight: bold;}
 </style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 1</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 2</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 3</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 4</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 5</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 6</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 7</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 8</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 9</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 10</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 11</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 12</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 13</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 14</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 15</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide a [mcve] with all the details.

Comment: Apologies, i have added the checkbox list in the question. Didnt initially include as was using [] positions anyways

Comment: I have tried my best to get a solution for you. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the other answer, I made it well so that if one of those hot areas are selected (and can be configured), you won't be able to select the others and also others gets unselected.

So technically, what I am doing here:

- Select the magic ones, others except magic ones will be disabled and unselected.
- When all the magic ones are unselected, others behave normal.
- At any point of time, you won't be able to have magic as well as muggles selected.
- You don't need to go by indices, but instead, you can add a class `magic` to the input.

* *By magic ones I mean, those are not supposed to be selected.*

```js
$(".parent input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("magic")) {
    if (this.checked)
      $(".parent input[type='checkbox']:not(.magic)").prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
    else {
      if ($(".parent input.magic[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 0)
        $(".parent input[type='checkbox']:not(.magic)").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
label {display: block;}
.magic + span {font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 1</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 2</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 3</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 4</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 5</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 6</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 7</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 8</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="magic" /> <span>Input 9</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="magic" /> <span>Input 10</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="magic" /> <span>Input 11</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 12</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 13</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 14</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 15</span></label>
</div>
```

**Update:** Fixed the syntax error and added labels. Added visual cues. Some code clean-up done.

---

If you prefer not to add classes, but just the indices, well, extending my answer, you get here:

```js
var indices = [9, 10, 11];

indices.forEach(function (i) {
  $(".parent input[type='checkbox']").eq(i-1).addClass("magic");
});
$(".parent input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("magic")) {
    if (this.checked)
      $(".parent input[type='checkbox']:not(.magic)").prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true);
    else {
      if ($(".parent input.magic[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 0)
        $(".parent input[type='checkbox']:not(.magic)").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
label {display: block;}
.magic + span {font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 1</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 2</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 3</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 4</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 5</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 6</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 7</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 8</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 9</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 10</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 11</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 12</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 13</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 14</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /> <span>Input 15</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your second answer looks good! if i copy and paste that into my application it does not work for some reason

Comment: @lanes123 Oh, what happens in the console? Any errors?

Comment: no errors, it just allows you to select them all like it isnt being applied

Comment: @lanes123 Any way you can replicate it somewhere, so that I can have a look?

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, but i put the query in script tags, then the css then the htm, is this right? sometimes the order in which they come affects it.. i will post as an answer how i have done it, then will delete it once you have seen it?

Comment: Yea, that's right. Can you edit the question and update?

Comment: i have added to the question what exactly i added into my application, is there any issues in this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `index()` and `eq` here...

First try to find the index of clicked checkbox using **[index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)**...Then if it matches with the condition(9, 10 or 11) disable all using **[prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)** and also add a class to the checked checkbox to check the count of **matched+checked** checkbox...And later if this count become `0` enable all the checkboxes

***Note:*** `index()` and `eq()` starts from 0

```js
$(".parent input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
  $(this).on("change", function() {
    var index = $(this).closest("label").index();
    if (index === 8 || index === 9 || index === 10) {
      $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", true);
      $("input[type='checkbox']").eq(8).prop("disabled", false);
      $("input[type='checkbox']").eq(9).prop("disabled", false);
      $("input[type='checkbox']").eq(10).prop("disabled", false);
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      if (this.checked) {
        $(this).addClass("matched");
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("matched");
      }
      if ($(".matched").length === 0) {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", false);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>1</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>2</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>3</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>4</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>5</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>6</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>7</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>8</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>9</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>10</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>11</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>12</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>13</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>14</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check"><span>15</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: In this way, you won't be able to unselect.

Comment: @PraveenKumar unselect what..?

Comment: Say I select 9 and found out, oops, I meant to select 8, I won't be able to do. Get it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar but if you select 9, OP wants to disable all including 9 except 10, 11

Comment: Okay, I really don't understand it. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to check boxes that you want to disable as follow.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        if (this.value == 'example9' || this.value == 'example10' || this.value == 'example11') {
          $('.test').attr('disabled', true);
        }
      } else {
        if (this.value == 'example9' || this.value == 'example10' || this.value == 'example11') {
          if ($("input[type='checkbox']:not(.test):checked").length == 0)
             $('.test').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' value='example1' class='test' />1</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example2' class='test' />2</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example3' class='test' />3</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example4' class='test' />4</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example5' class='test' />5</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example6' class='test' />6</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example7' class='test' />7</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example8' class='test' />8</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example9' />9</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example10' />10</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example11' />11</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example12' class='test' />12</br>
<input type='checkbox' value='example13' class='test' />13</br>
```

Comment: This allows the selection when you unselect and there are 9 10 or 11 still selected.

Comment: works like a charm! 2 quick questions, is there a way of doing it without given them all a class name? And, is there a way of unchecking the ones that are checked (if 9,10,11 are checked)

Comment: @lanes123 Did you check my answer and explanation? I have got your all queries answered there.

Comment: Guys, try checking 9, then 10, and uncheck 9 and you will be able to select others... `:D`